# Rails remembering wrong fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have a page which has a login form, as well as a form to register. Here is the code:

```
<h3>Log In</h2>
<%= form_for Spree::User.new, :as => :spree_user, :url => spree.spree_user_session_path  do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %>
  <div><%= f.submit "Log In", class: "registrationbuttons" %></div>
<% end %>

<h3>Register Now</h2>
<%= form_for Spree::User.new, :as => :spree_user, :url => spree.spree_user_registration_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
  <div><%= f.submit "Register", class: "registrationbuttons" %></div>
<% end %>
```

If a user uses the Log In form, and is asked if they want their browser to remember the password - If they select yes the next time they see this page, fields in the Register Now form (which they may have never user) populate.

How can I ensure only the correct fields get saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://benjaminjshore.info/2014/05/chrome-auto-fill-honey-pot-hack.html

I added this line:

```
<input type="password" name="password_fake" id="password_fake" value="" style="display:none;" />
```

To my 2nd form_for (the fields which were being incorrectly remembered). It now looks like this:

```
<%= form_for Spree::User.new, :as => :spree_user, :url => spree.spree_user_registration_path do |f| %>
    <!-- fake fields are a workaround for chrome autofill getting the wrong fields -->
    <input type="password" name="password_fake" id="password_fake" value="" style="display:none;" />
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm Password" %><br>
  <div><%= f.submit "Register", class: "registrationbuttons" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Now the field is not remembered.